# Prevent delete last-child javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML code

```
<div class="form_group">
    <div id="p_scents">
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="addAffiliate()">+ Add Merchant ID</a> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="deleteAffiliate()">X</a>
            <p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" required="true"  size="30" class="form-control" name="merchant[]" value="<?php echo $keys->affiliate ?>" placeholder="Input MerchantID" /></label>  </p>
          <p></p></div>
    <hr>
```

When I press `X` it will delete the last-child. But i want that the remaining 1 child or the first-child will not be deleted..like there is a warning..

Javascript

```
function addAffiliate()
{
   var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
   var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;
    $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" required="true" id=id="p_scnt_'+i+'"size="30" class="form-control" name="merchant[]" value="" placeholder="Input MerchantID" /></label>  </p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            i++;      
}

function deleteAffiliate()
{
     $('#p_scents p:last-child').remove();
}
```

Comment: Just test the length of the children > 1

Comment: Does `$('#p_scents p + p:last-child').remove()` work for you?

Comment: yes..my only problem is to prevent from deleting the first-child..:D

Comment: Sounds like you might be looking for an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if more than 1 item exists.  If so, remove it.

```
function deleteAffiliate()
{
  var $items = $('#p_scents p');
  if ($items.length > 1) {
    $items.last().remove();
  } else {
    alert("At least 1 item must remain. Not deleting.");
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks! i already got the answer before your post..:D Anyway thanks..:D